# Symfony2: UniqueValidator for form

Tags: dependency-injection, symfony, validation

I have a RegistrationFormType with following validation constraints:

```
public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'email' => array(
                new NotBlank(),
                new Email(array('message' => 'Ungültige E-Mail Adresse')),
                ),
            'username' => new Unique(),
            'code' => new MaxLength(array('limit'=>20)),
            'plainPassword' => new MaxLength(array('limit'=>20)),
        ));

        return array(
            'csrf_protection' => false,
            'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint,
        );
    }
```

In order to assure uniqueness I created a Unique Class (extending Contraint) and a UniqueValidator (extending ConstraintValidator) like described here: http://www.michelsalib.com/2011/04/create-your-own-constraint-validator-in-symfony2-a-doctrine-unique-validator/

The problem is, I get following error on submitting the form:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to ...\Validation\Constraint\UniqueValidator::__construct() must be an instance of Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager, none given
```

It seems that the EntityManager is not injected into the ConstraintValidator, I created a service definition in my config.yml though:

```
services:
    eventiply.validator.unique:
        class: Ajado\EventHubBundle\Validation\UniqueValidator
        arguments: 
            entityManager: "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
        tags:
            - { name: validator.constraint_validator, alias: validator.unique }
```

Any ideas how I could progress here?

Comment: I'm having a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8403440). I never solved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem:

I had following code in my Unique Constraint:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Unique extends Constraint{
    public $message = 'Dieser Wert muss eindeutig sein, ist leider aber schon vergeben';
    public $propertyName;
    public $property;
    public $entityName;

    public function __construct($options = null) {

        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    { 
        // copied that from http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html
        return get_class($this).'Validator';
    }
}
```

And this is the corrected one:

```
/**
 * @Annotation
 */
class Unique extends Constraint{
    public $message = 'Dieser Wert muss eindeutig sein, ist leider aber schon vergeben';

    public function __construct($options = null) {

        parent::__construct($options);
    }

    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'validator.unique';
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your YAML looks off. The `arguments` value should be an array, not a hash:

```
arguments:
    - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Comment: changed it- without any effect